# retain value selected in HTML select tag

Tags: html, html-select

[image]

I'm creating a way for customers to tip on top of an order.  However when you "update" the total, the select value will always go back to $0.  Is there a way to retain the value so that, even if the page is refreshed, the user's selected tip is shown?

i know the select tag has a "selected" attribute, but I'm not sure how i would make it work for me.

Comment: you mean page refresh or after clicking update? Using just pure html after page refresh it is not possible to retain values as HTTP is a stateless protocol

Answer (score 1):

On the change event of the tip select menu, you could set a cookie or use local storage and save the value that way. Then on DOM ready, simply read the cookie or local storage value and update the select menu.

If you don't care about http traffic, you could also make an ajax call to your server on the same change event handler and set a session variable. Then when you're outputting the HTML, the `selected` property can be applied to the option that matches the session var.

Untested, but something like this should work:

```
$(function(){
    var savedTip = localStorage.getItem('tipVal');
    if (savedTip) {
        $('#tip').val(savedTip);
        localStorage.removeItem('tipVal'); // garbage collection
    }

    $('#tip').on('change', function(e) {
        localStorage.setItem('tipVal', $(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: in your first solution, how do you just select the correct value? do you have sample html for that option?

Comment: That's my example code - you don't use the `selected="selected"` since the client-side script is what's responsible for setting the value, and it happens after the select menu is already in the DOM.